# JS function not running whole script

Tags: javascript

this part of my JS

```
  var records=response.split('|');
  for (i=1; i<records.length; i++) {
    var record=records[i].split('*');
    var region=record[0];
    var regionid=record[1];
    var x=document.createElement('option');
    x.text=region;
   list.options.add(x);
   }
```

when it gets to the for loop, it never runs the stuff between { }

records is

```
0: "<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option>"
length: 1
```

response is

```
"<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option>"
```

so why does it not run the items between { }?

EDIT********

when changed to 0 so it does run, it will now make the drop box option say

```
<option>
      "<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option>"
</option>
```

What instead it should do is break each of the options into there own option for the drop down box.

Comment: no the value of records.length  is 1

Comment: That's the problem; `1` is equal to `1`, not less than it. Your loop will never execute. You may want to set `i` to `0`, or the `<` to `=`... or just remove the condition entirely if it will always be met.

Comment: then the loop will not run since i = 1 is never less than 1 .... you should start with i = 0

Comment: try change i<records.length to i<=records.length to include the equal

Comment: that works, but then my drop box now just says [code]<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option>[/code]

Comment: so maybe i have more issues.  .

Comment: May be you can explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish, and the desired result (modify the main post). Thanks

Comment: updated main post

Comment: Why are you using `split()` to try to parse HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split function is returning an array of size 1 because it is not finding a pipe '|' in your string.  Meanwhile, Javascript array indexes are zero based, so the first and only item is record[0].  Since your loop only starts looping on the second or higher record due to the "i=1;" initializer, it never runs because "i<records.length;" is false from the get go.

I think there's two bugs here:

1) Initialize your for loop at zero (ie, "i=0;")

2) You probably need to split on a different pattern since there are no pipes in your string.  Maybe try:

```
var valueRegEx = /value='([^']+)'/;  // find the contents of the value attribute
var textRegEx = />([^<]*)/;  // find the text of the option

var records=response.split('</option><option ');
for (i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
  var option = record[i];
  var value = valueRegEx.exec(option)[1]
  var text = textRegEx.exec(option)[1]

  // ...
  // Not sure what you're trying to do at this part,
  // but the above hopefully answers your question 
  // ...

  var x=document.createElement('option');
  x.text=region;
  list.options.add(x);
}
```

Another way to retrieve all the values from the response string is just to let a regular expression parse out the whole thing:

```
var regex = /(?<=value=['"])[^'"]*/g;

var arrayOfValues = response.match(regex);
// arrayOfValues = ['Bobs Dock', 'Johns Dock', 'Mikes Dock']
```

Comment: what you said made me re-think.   Why not just supply the values i needed separate by |    So while i did not go this route (cause i was able to change the response i needed) this way did work.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer explained, there is a bug on the loop. Start at 0 for i, but this answer is mainly focusing on the remaining part.

A slightly different take on the same problem. Instead of splitting using regex or other separators, I'm making it a proper HTML and then get the options as an HTMLCollection.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hari7190/mbugyz24/

```
var response = "<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option><option value='Mayur Dock'>Mayur Dock</option><option value='Foo Dock'>Foo Dock</option>"

parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString("<select>" + response + "</select>", "text/html");
var options = doc.getElementsByTagName("option");

for(i=0; i<options.length; i++){
    var x=document.createElement('option');
    x.text = options[i].text;
    x.value= options[i].value
    document.getElementById("list").append(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be designed for a completely different format of response, e.g.

```
Bobs Doc*1|Johns Dock*2|Mikes Dock*3
```

But your actual response is just the HTML for the options, so you don't need to construct the HTML in your own loop. You can simply add it to the HTML of the `<select>`:

```
list.innerHTML += response;
```